# Get BigQuery to read all CSV files in a Drive Folder (same schema)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

Is it possible to have a BigQuery query on a Google Drive folder if all CSV files in the folder have the same schema? Is it possible for the query to be updated automatically whenever a file is added or deleted? Just wondering whether this would require some Apps script or can just be done within BigQuery somehow.

Comment: It can be done via Drive API push notifications (check the reference documentation for more details). Unfortunately, you cannot implement Drive API push notifications with Google Apps Script. You're going to need something more robust, like a GCP Cloud Function.

Comment: Hi there @user3511512! It is true that you can use [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push) to accomplish your goal, as @TheAddonDepot said. To make it run, we could help you to set up the push notifications, but you would need to configure your own domain and server as it's described in the linked docs. If you are aware of those requirements, is using the push notifications a valid method for you?

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1: PubSub detection of Google Drive changes

You can likely do this [via PubSub](https://www.clairvoyant.ai/blog/enabling-google-drive-api-push-notifications-with-pub-sub-messaging).

Then have the PubSub subscription be a [PUSH notification](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push) to an [Apps Script web service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) HTTP endpoint.

Your `doGet()` method in Apps Script can then do your normal import actions on that CSV based on the filename passed as a parameter in the PubSub HTTP push notification.

### Option 2: Use BQ external tables

Link BQ to an [external Google Drive source](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-drive) as an [external table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-tables). This does not require "importing" data to BQ at all, it reads directly from CSV on Google Drive, etc.